# How to show div based on data sent to blade in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

i have two divs (`inputbarang` and `inputkategori`). I want to make one of the divs disappear when there's no data in it. For example, when the `$produk`'s value is not null, the `inputbarang`'s div will appear, and the `inputkategori`'s div will be hidden. Whereas, if `$produk` is empty, then the `inputbarang`'s div will be hidden and the `inputkategori`'s div will appear. I try like this. When `$produk` is null, the `inputbarang`'s div still appears and the `inputkategori`'s div doesn't appear

**Blade.php**:

```
@if($produk !== null)
<div class="form-group row " id="inputbarang" >
    <label class="col-form-label col-lg-3 col-sm-12">Barang</label>
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-9 col-sm-12">
        <select class="form-control m-select2" width="500px" id="kt_select2_1" name="id_product[]" multiple="multiple">
        @foreach($productall as $p)
        @if(in_array($p->id, $productbyIds))
        <option value="{{ $p->id }}" selected="true">{{ $p->product }}</option>
        @else
        <option value="{{ $p->id }}">{{ $p->product }}</option>
        @endif 
        @endforeach
        </select>
    </div>
</div>

@else
<div class="form-group row" id="inputkategori" >
    <label class="col-form-label col-lg-3 col-sm-12">Kategori</label>
    <div class="col-lg-9 col-md-9 col-sm-12">
        <select class="form-control m-select2" width="500px" id="kt_select2_3" name="id_kategori[]" multiple="multiple">
        @foreach($kategoriall as $k)
        @if(in_array($k->id, $kategoribyIds))
        <option value="{{ $k->id }}" selected="true">{{ $k->kategori }}</option>
        @else
        <option value="{{ $k->id }}">{{ $k->kategori }}</option>
        @endif
        @endforeach
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
@endif
```

**Controller**:

```
$produk = Produk::where('m_product.delete', 0)
            ->join('tb_promo_detail', 'tb_promo_detail.id_product','=','m_product.id')
            ->select('m_product.id', 'm_product.product')
            ->where('tb_promo_detail.id_promo',$id)
            ->get();
```

Please correct me if its wrong.. Thank you so much!

Comment: What is not working? Is both div being shown? or only one being shown. Please let me know what gets displayed.

Comment: It is very difficult to understand your question.

Comment: when $produk is null, it still show `inputbarang` div, not `inputkategori` @DeepeshThapa

Comment: have you check value of  `$produk` using `dd()`?

Comment: @Shany it really dosent make sense really. You might have been sending a null value.. Can you try with this code `@if($produk)` instead of `@if($produk !== null)`

Comment: Also try `@if($produk != null)`

Comment: yes, when `$produk` is null, it returns null array @vinod

Comment: None of those are work... @DeepeshThapa

Comment: so `$produk` is an array?

Comment: yes it is @DeepeshThapa

Comment: @Shany try `@if(empty($produk))` instead of `@if($produk !== null)`

Comment: now it works on `inputkategori` but not works on `inputbarang`.. im sorry.. @DeepeshThapa

Comment: I really dont know what you are sending on `$produk` from the controller. I cant really tell without looking at your controller method.

Comment: try `@if(empty($produk) || $produk != null)`

Comment: I have editted my question with the controller.. @DeepeshThapa

Comment: Check my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are sending a collection to your blade from controller you will need to check if that collection is empty or not. Just checking if it is null or empty array will not give you the right conditional effect.

So use:

```
@if($produk->first())
```

or you can also use

```
@if(!$produk->isEmpty())
```